# Interleave text files with a given ratio of lines from file1 to file2

Tags: bash, shell, text, awk

I have 2 text files. One contains 3x the number of lines as the other. The smaller one contains headers which I would like to interleave with the lines of the larger text file in a 3:1 ratio

e.g.

small file:

```
header1
header2
header3
```

big file

```
lines1.1
lines1.2
lines1.3
lines2.1
lines2.2
lines2.3
lines3.1
lines3.2
lines3.3
```

becomes:

```
header1
lines1.1
lines1.2
lines1.3
header2
lines2.1
lines2.2
lines2.3
header3
lines3.1
lines3.2
lines3.3
```

I have a shell solution to my problem:

```sh
new_reads_no="$(wc -l small_file.txt | awk '{print $1}')"
sequence="$(seq 1 $new_reads_no)"

for i in $sequence
do
    start=$((3*($i-1)+1))
    end=$(($start+2))
    awk -v c1=$i 'FNR==c1' small_file.txt >> Output.txt
    awk -v s="$start" -v e="$end" 'NR>=s&&NR<=e' big_file.txt >> Output.txt
done
```

Which works great. However, my small file is 10 million lines. At the rate it's going at the moment, I've estimated it will be finished in about 1 year.

Any help speeding this up would be much appreciated. Either a simple shell loop-free one liner or even just a quick tool in another language would be awesome.

Comment: if you have `GNU sed`, see how's the performance for `sed -e 'R f2' -e 'R f2' -e 'R f2' f1` where `f1` is the smaller file

Comment: as to why your current solution is slow, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Sundeep Your link is useful, but that's not at all what's going on here.

Comment: Perfect! The sed line is exactly what I'm looking for. Genuinely did in about 5 seconds what would have taken a year

Answer (score 5):

**Good old `paste`:**

```
paste -d '\n' fsmall - - - <fbig
```

> **SYNOPSIS** `paste [-s] [-d list] file ... file` 
> **OPERANDS** *file*: A pathname of an input file. If `-` is specified for one or more of the files, the standard input shall be used; the standard input shall be read one line at a time, circularly, for each instance of `-`.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX paste](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html)</sub>**

This means, each <hyphen>-character reads a line from `stdin`, which is defined to be `fbig` in this case. Three hyphens, means three lines.

**Good old `awk` without buffering:**

```
awk -v r=3 '1;{for(i=1;i<=r;++i) {getline < "-"; print}}' fsmall <fbig
```

This method mimicks the idea of the `paste`-solution. It uses `getline` to avoid buffering of the small file. This is not really flexible and one should always be careful when using `getline` [See [All about getline](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline)]

**Good old `awk` with buffering:**

```
awk -v r=3 '(NR==FNR){b[FNR]=$0;next}(FNR%r==1){print b[++c]}1' fsmall fbig
```

This buffers the small file. This could lead to performance issues when the small file is really big. (See the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112878/interleave-text-files-with-a-given-ratio-of-lines-from-file1-to-file2/60114757?noredirect=1#comment106322794_60114757) of Tripleee)

Comment: The Awk solution reads the entire smaller file into memory; if you have enough memory, that's fine, but it won't degrade very gracefully if you don't.

Comment: @kvantour `paste` is very good but `awk` giving wrong results.

Comment: @tripleee correct. I've added an un-buffered version (similar behaviour to paste)

Comment: @Ivan there was a typo

Comment: @kvantour it's awesom

Answer (score 4):

With `GNU sed`

```
sed -e 'R f2' -e 'R f2' -e 'R f2' f1
```

where `f1` is the smaller file. The `R` command reads one line at a time from the given file. The lines thus obtained gets appended after the current line that's read from `f1`

Answer (score 2):

Repeatedly reopening each input file and seeking to the spot where you last stopped reading is horribly inefficient.  Making matters worse, you are reading the *entire* input file through to the end each time, and just picking out one line or three along the way. You could at least `exit` as soon as you have printed the stuff you wanted. But hang on.

Here is a simple Python script which does what you are asking for by simply keeping both files open and reading from each as you go.

```py
with open('small_file.txt') as small, open('big_file.txt') as large:
    for line in small:
        print(line, end='')
        for x in range(3):
            print(large.readline(), end='')
```

If you would like to parametrize the file names, try

```py
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as small, open(sys.argv[2]) as large:
    ...
```

Output is to standard output, so if you saved the above into `path/to/script.py` you can simply run this at the shell prompt:

```
python3 path/to/script.py small_file.txt big_file.txt >Output.txt
```

The use of `end=''` is a minor hack to avoid having to pluck off the newline and have `print` add it back.

As an afterthought, you can do much the same thing in a shell script;

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    for x in 1 2 3; do
        IFS= read -u 3 -r other
        printf '%s\n' "$other"
    done
done <small_file.txt 3<big_file.txt >Output.txt
```

but the shell's `while read -r` loop is inherently much slower.

Comment: `read -u fh` is a Bash extension. It should not be too hard to recast the Bash script as a POSIX `sh` script but it's not going to be very fast so let's not bother.

Comment: if you go with Bash4+, `mapfile` callback is quite efficiently reading all 3 lines at once and printing header: `while IFS= read -r;do mapfile -tn3 -u3 -C'echo "$REPLY";:' -c3;printf '%s\n' "${MAPFILE[@]}";done <small_file.txt 3<big_file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

With Bash version 4 and above:

```sh
while IFS= read -r; do
  # Map 3 lines of big_file.txt without capturing newline character
  mapfile -t -n 3 -u 3

  # Output header $REPLY from small_file.txt
  # followed by ${MAPFILE[@]} mapped lines of big_file.txt
  printf '%s\n' "$REPLY" "${MAPFILE[@]}"
done <small_file.txt 3<big_file.txt
```

With a call-back to print header lines:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r; do
  mapfile -t -n 3 -u 3 -C'echo "$REPLY";:' -c 3
  printf '%s\n' "${MAPFILE[@]}"
done <small_file.txt 3<big_file.txt
```

`mapfile` is used to read 3 lines at a time from file-handle 3:

- `-t`: Do not capture newline character.
- `-n 3`: Map 3 lines into the `MAPFILE` array.
- `-u`: Read from file-handle 3 that is pointed to `big_file.txt`.
- `-C'echo "$REPLY";:'`: Call-back instructions.
- `-c 3`: Quantum to invoke the call-back (every 3 mapped lines).

The call-back:

- `echo "$REPLY"`: Output the `$REPLY` variable that contains the line read from the `small_file.txt` in the `while` loop.
- `:`: Dummy NOP command to consume the arguments passed to the call-back from the `mapfile` command.

`mapfile`'s call-back lacks documentation about its arguments. Here they are:

1. Last array index mapped
2. Last array value mapped

Answer (score 2):

If your small file is small enough to fit in memory:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{hdrs[NR]=$0; next} NR%3 == 1{print hdrs[++c]} 1' small big
header1
lines1.1
lines1.2
lines1.3
header2
lines2.1
lines2.2
lines2.3
header3
lines3.1
lines3.2
lines3.3
```

otherwise:

```
$ awk '(NR%3 == 1) && ((getline hdr < "small") > 0){print hdr} 1' big
header1
lines1.1
lines1.2
lines1.3
header2
lines2.1
lines2.2
lines2.3
header3
lines3.1
lines3.2
lines3.3
```

See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for why I'm using the syntax I'm using to call `getline` and why it's best avoided if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't slept because of that. This `R` command pointed by Sundeep is really cool but implementation is kind of frustrating. So i dug a bit in sed's docs, and found this `first~step`

```
   first~step
          Match  every  step'th  line starting with line first.  For example, ``sed -n 1~2p'' will print all the odd-numbered lines in the input stream,
          and the address 2~5 will match every fifth line, starting with the second.  first can be zero; in this case, sed operates as if it were  equal
          to step.  (This is an extension.)
```

And i've tried this

```
sed '1~3R headers' lines
```

But result was not as expected

```
line1.1
header1
line1.2
line1.3
line2.1
header2
line2.2
line2.3
line3.1
header3
line3.2
```

Because `R` is appending lines, this can be avoided by addind an extra first line to the lines file

```
sed -i '1s/^/\n/' lines
```

Than we process files

```
sed '1~3R headers' lines > output
```

And remove this extra line from output

```
sed -i '1d' output
```

But this necessity of adding removing lines is kind of frustrating also.
Is there a better way?

I wonder is grep fast enough? Could you try it?

```
headers=( $(cat headers) )
for header in ${headers[@]}; {
    echo $header >> output
    digit=${header//[!0-9]/}
    grep .*$digit. lines >> output
}
```

Ok which method is faster? I've made test files with this

```
for i in {1..100}; { echo "header$i" >> headers; }
for i in {1..100}; { for e in {1..3}; { echo "line$i.$e" >> lines;}; }
```

100 and 300 lines, and tested all methods

```
paste -d '\n' headers - - - <lines

real    0m0,003s
user    0m0,000s
sys     0m0,003s

sed -e 'R lines' -e 'R lines' -e 'R lines' headers

real    0m0,003s
user    0m0,000s
sys     0m0,003s

awk -v r=3 '1;{for(i=1;i<=r;++i) {getline < "-"; print}}' headers <lines
awk -v r=3 '(NR==FNR){b[FNR]=$0;next}(FNR%r==1){print b[++c]}1' headers lines

real    0m0,005s
user    0m0,000s
sys     0m0,005s
```

Those are clear winners. And this also fast but incorrect.

```
$ time awk 'NR==FNR{hdrs[NR]=$0; next} NR%3 == 1{print hdrs[++c]} 1' headers lines | head -n7
line1.1
line1.2
header1
line1.3
line2.1
line2.2
header2

real    0m0,004s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,003s
```

Ok this is what TS use.

```
fun1 () {
    new_reads_no="$(wc -l headers | awk '{print $1}')"
    sequence="$(seq 1 $new_reads_no)"

    for i in $sequence
    do
        start=$((3*($i-1)+1))
        end=$(($start+2))
        awk -v c1=$i 'FNR==c1' headers
        awk -v s="$start" -v e="$end" 'NR>=s&&NR<=e' lines
    done
}

real    0m0,341s
user    0m0,219s
sys     0m0,132s
```

Well, this is not fast at all)

```
fun2 () {
    headers=( $(cat headers) )
    for header in ${headers[@]}; {
        echo $header
        digit=${header//[!0-9]/}
        grep .*$digit. lines
    }
}

real    0m0,167s
user    0m0,105s
sys     0m0,068s
```

Mine is also fail, but still it's faster than the 1-st one)
So i got what is realy needed here and made this one.

```
fun3 () {
    exec 3< headers
    exec 4< lines

    while read -u3 head do;
        echo $head
        for i in {1..3}; {
            read -u4 line; echo $line
        }
    done

    exec 3<&-
    exec 4<&-
}

real    0m0,009s
user    0m0,009s
sys     0m0,000s
```

And it's quite fast)

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as small, open(sys.argv[2]) as large:
    for line in small:
        print(line, end='')
        for x in range(3):
            print(large.readline(), end='')


real    0m0,021s
user    0m0,016s
sys     0m0,004s
```

Python quite good also.
And this two also good.

```
fun4 () {
    while IFS= read -r; do
      # Map 3 lines of big_file.txt without capturing newline character
      mapfile -t -n 3 -u 3

      # Output header $REPLY from small_file.txt
      # followed by ${MAPFILE[@]} mapped lines of big_file.txt
      printf '%s\n%s' "$REPLY" "${MAPFILE[@]}"
    done <lines 3<headers
}

real    0m0,017s
user    0m0,012s
sys     0m0,004s

fun5 () {
    while IFS= read -r; do
      mapfile -t -n 3 -u 3 -C'echo "$REPLY";:' -c 3
      printf '%s\n' "${MAPFILE[@]}"
    done <headers 3<lines
}

real    0m0,011s
user    0m0,011s
sys     0m0,000s
```

Comment: This will have the same problem as the original solution, plus it assumes the contents of the files are completely regular, which in practice they are probably not (then the OP could simply generate the output without looking at either of these files).

Comment: @tripleee it's faster than your py script) But `paste` by kvantour or `sed` by Sundeep are unbeatable

Comment: Did you test it on 10 M lines of input? There are several regex problems here which should become apparent if you have more than just toy data (shorter digit sequences will match longer ones, and you forgot to escape the final dot; the leading `.*` is unnecessary but harmless).

Comment: Yep on bigger file it's sucks(

Comment: to be clear, you don't have an awk solution in your timing tests. That shell loop calling awk repeatedly is a shell solution, not an awk one. Nothing involving a shell loop will be as fast as a single call to one command and it'll usually be more complicated, less portable, and buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's edit bigfile directy via `ed(1)` plus shell.

Save the smallfile in an array.

```
mapfile -t array < smallfile
```

Mapfile is a bash4 feature, bash3 you can do.

```
array=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
   array+=("$line")
done < smallfile
```

Count the number of lines in bigfile plus the interval where we will insert the smallfiles line and save it in an array named `count`

```
count=(); for ((i=1;i<=$(wc -l < bigfile); i += 4 )); do count+=("$i"); done
```

Although `printf '%s\n' '$=' | ed -s bigfile` can count the total number of lines in bigfile, `wc` is written for that kind of purpose. `$(wc -l < bigfile)`

Write the changes to bigfile by copying lines from smallfile.

```
printf '%s\n' "${count[0]}i" "${array[0]}" . "${count[1]}i" "${array[1]}" . "${count[2]}i" "${array[2]}" . w | ed -s bigfile
```